# Get the rtpL16 data into local file | How to check the file is as expected?

Tags: c++11, audio, gstreamer, pcm, audio-processing

As the headline (title), there are 2 questions that I am facing here.

**1. Getting Rtp payload into a local file.**

Now this I have accomplished as below

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! filesink location=TestFile.pcm
```

But I am not sure how to close the file properly!!!
Right now what I am doing is turn off the source pipeline *(It turns off automatically when the audio file reaches its end)*. And that stops writing the data on the file. Is there a way that the client side pipeline *(the one given above)* would recognize that there is no incoming data and so the pipeline gets free.

**2. How to check the file generated TestFile.pcm**

The file that is generated from above pipeline contains raw audio data. How to play that (the linux based audio file player (mplayer) is not able to play it) to check whether the sent and received data is the same.

Please help. Any suggestion or advice will be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: The second part of the question is now resolved. Using audacity player to check the raw audio data. (File > Import > RawData)

Comment: Hey, as a heads up, this question will be more visible if you swap out one of your tags with the c++ tag. People tend to watch c++ more than c++11.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try experimenting with the property `timeout` of element `udpsrc`. Write a logic that makes your pipeline stop in the callback function of timeout.
2. Have you tried saving the file in different formats? like mp4, avi, etc. Do you know if any encoding was done at the source? If it is done then you must use appropriate decoder after element `rtpL16depay` to decode the video from that codec format to raw format. May be this is the reason, you are not able to play the file. 
   This may be a wild guess, but I think L16 can be your encoding format at source.

Comment: HI @vk_gst The part of checking the output is correct or not is done by audacity player. and i have tried with PCM mulaw which works for my application. I have not explored other possibilities due to time constraints. I am still stuck at the closing of pipeline part of the question.

Comment: are there any good examples on how to use `timeout` property?

Comment: you just need to mention,`timeout= <some value>`, and write a callback function that will be called by monitoring the bus.  Check this [link](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/timeout-not-working-td4665437.html) for some examples.